# Gate NAND in JAVA

Tags: java

This time I have `NAND Gate` and `NOR Gate` in which I'm failing only one test in each one. In `NAND` when the input signals are, let's say, `0X` `(LOW and UNKNOWN SIGNAL)` the output should be `1` but I'm getting `X`. In NOR, when I have a mix of `1` (HI Signals) and `X` (Unknown Signals) the answer should be `0` but Im getting `X` Im failing only a single test case involving `0` and `X` together and the output of them via NAN should be `1`. In the method when I check for `Signal.X` the `boolean` becomes `true` but does it break from the loop?

```
  Table NAND for reference.(NOTE:table does not contain X)

         Input A    Input B     Output Q
              0       0           1
              0       1           1
              1       0           1
              1       1           0

    Table NOR for reference.(NOTE:table does not contain X)

Input A     Input B     Output Q
    0          0           1
    0          1           0
    1          0           0
    1          1           0




//in NAND propagate when the inputs are 0X or 000X0X the output should be 1, Im //getting X
 public boolean propagate() //NAND method
        {
            Signal inputSignal;
            Signal temp = getOutput().getSignal();
            List<Wire> inputs = getInputs();
            boolean hasX = false;
            int countLO = 0;
            int countHI = 0;

            for(Wire wire: inputs)
            {
                inputSignal = wire.getSignal();

                if(inputSignal == Signal.X)
                    hasX = true;

                else if(inputSignal == Signal.LO)
                    countLO++;

                else if(inputSignal == Signal.HI)
                    countHI++;
            }

            if(hasX)
                getOutput().setSignal(Signal.X);

            else if(countLO == inputs.size())
                getOutput().setSignal(Signal.HI);

            else if(countHI == inputs.size())
                getOutput().setSignal(Signal.LO);

            else
                getOutput().setSignal(Signal.HI);

.................................


//in NOR propagate when the inputs are 1X1X or 1X the output should be X, Im //getting X

public boolean propagate() //NOR method
    {
        Signal inputSignal;
        int countLO = 0;
        boolean hasX = false;
        List<Wire> inputs = getInputs();
        Signal temp = getOutput().getSignal();

        for(Wire wire: inputs)
        {
            inputSignal = wire.getSignal();

            if(inputSignal == Signal.X)
            {
                hasX = true;
                break;
            }

            else if(inputSignal == Signal.LO)
                countLO++;
        }

        if(hasX)
            getOutput().setSignal(Signal.X);

        else if(countLO != inputs.size())
            getOutput().setSignal(Signal.LO);

        else getOutput().setSignal(Signal.HI);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tables should include X so that we can see what the program is supposed to do. Anyway, the problem seems to be in the line `if(hasX) getOutput().setSignal(Signal.X);`. Since that's the first line in the nested if statement it takes priority over anything else. So if there's any `X` in the input, `getOutput().setSignal(Signal.X)` will be called.